# Having Trouble Populating an Array of Structures from Reading a File

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to populate an array with values from this file:

```
9383      8.86
2777     69.15
7793     83.35
5386      4.92
6649     14.21
2362      0.27
8690      0.59
7763     39.26
 540     34.26
9172     57.36
5211     53.68
2567     64.29
5782     15.30
2862     51.23
4067     31.35
3929     98.02
4022     30.58
3069     81.67
1393     84.56
5011     80.42
6229     73.73
4421     49.19
3784     85.37
5198     43.24
8315     43.70
6413     35.26
6091     89.80
9956     18.73
6862     91.70
6996     72.81
```

Here is my code, it successfully compiles but I get "segmentation fault, core dumped" when I go to run the code.

```
typedef struct student
{
double score;
int id;
char grades;
} Student;


void main(void)
{
    char filename[] = "scores.dat";
    FILE *input;
    Student class[MAXNUM];
    int numScores;
    double average;

    input = fopen("scores.dat", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
            printf("EOF");
            exit(1);
    }
    getScores(input, class[MAXNUM]);
}


int getScores(FILE *input, Student class[])
{
    double s;
    int i, j, count = 0;

    while(fscanf(input, "%d %lf", &i, &s) == 2)
    {
            class[count].score = s;
            count++;
    }
    //loop to check what is in the array.
         for(j = 0; j< 20; j++){
            printf("%lf\n", class[j].score);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, I've never had a program compile but fail to run. I tried declaring the function getScores before main, but it only added an error when I went to compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just a comment unrelated to your question - `EOF` means end-of-file. If `input == null` that means that there was a problem opening the file for reading (it didn't exist, permissions, etc), not that you've reached the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in getScore parameters. Specifically in Stundent. You say you expect an array (class[]), but you are passing an object (class[MAXIMUM]). And you are out of bounds. Remember that an index starts from 0. That means that when you code, for example: int a[100]. The last element is in a[99], not a[100].

Set -Wall when you compile your program. The compiler is your friend. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the call:

`getScores(input, class[MAXNUM]);`

Change the above statement to this:

`getScores(input, class);`

And it will successfully run. What you were doing is that you were passing an element of the array, rather than the address of the array itself.

Output:

```
8.860000
69.150000
83.350000
4.920000
14.210000
0.270000
0.590000
39.260000
34.260000
57.360000
53.680000
64.290000
15.300000
51.230000
31.350000
98.020000
30.580000
81.670000
84.560000
80.420000
```